# Interaction terms of the same variable with multiple variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, interaction

I have a model

lm = a  ~ b

I would like to include c, d , e that represent interactions terms with b =>

lm = a  ~ b + b:c + b:d + b:e.

Is there a rapid way to obtain this result without taping each variable? I have more than 10 variables.

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is.  The way you show it should work just fine, `a ~ b + b:c + b:d + b:e`. You can use parentheses to save a tiny bit of typing, `a ~ b + b:(c + d + e)`.  You can use `.` as a stand-in for all non-response variables in the data, `a ~ b:(.)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I have many variables to add. I am looking for a way that does not imply a 30min typing ^^

Comment: Okay, `b:(.)` it is then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R formulas, `.` is a placeholder for all non-response variables present in the data.

```
coef(lm(mpg ~ wt:(.), data = mtcars))
 #  (Intercept)            wt        wt:cyl       wt:disp         wt:hp       wt:drat       wt:qsec 
 # 41.044844014 -16.742131313   0.028771226   0.006485611  -0.005048411   0.447194218   0.423909109 
 #        wt:vs         wt:am       wt:gear       wt:carb 
 # -0.087023686   0.402891966  -0.142805986   0.156345459
```

Comment: If I want to select specific columns and no all the responses variables ?

Comment: At some point if there are variable you want and variables you don't want, you'll have to let R know which  are which. There's probably a way to make it work using the names or even the column numbers of either set (those you want, or those you don't want). Or maybe you can specify a naming pattern (all variables starting with "year_"). If you want more help, ask another question that's more specific, perhaps giving an example of how you'd like to specify the variables you want (or don't want): name, naming pattern, column number, something else?